# Linq calculate average,total and compare the result in query

Tags: c#, linq

I am having trouble in following query that how to add if else in select block also I want some better way to write the following query

```
var x = csvParser.ParseCsv(@"data.csv");
var unsettledCustomers = x.GroupBy(g=>g.Id).
    Select(gg =>new
    {
        Id=g.Key,
        Total=g.Sum(xx=>xx.Stake),
        Avg=g.Average(ss=>ss.Win)
    });
```

Comment: `x.GroupBy(g=>g.Id).` - what is Id? You do not have it listed in your CVS data.

Comment: It's customerId first value in csv data

Comment: Is `bet` = `stake` ? Or are they 2 different things?

Comment: bet and stake are same thing

Comment: `Select` is for one to one mapping, what you need is to use `filter` and in that you can put condition `Total > 10 * Avg`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var unsettledCustomers = x.GroupBy(g => g.Id)
    .Select(g => new
    {
        Id = g.Key,
        Total = g.Sum(xx => xx.Stake),
        Avg = g.Average(ss => ss.Win),
        AvgerageBet = g.Average(ss => ss.Stake),
        UnusualBets = g.Where(bet => bet.Stake > (10 * g.Average(ss => ss.Stake))).ToList()
    });

var allUnusualBets = unsettledCustomers.SelectMany(y => y.UnusualBets);
```

---

Your posted question:

> I want to identify Bets where the stake (bet) is more than 10 times higher than that customer’s average bet in their betting history...

Your data where Id = the customer id. Note that there are no instances where the average bet * 10 is higher than the bet placed so there are no unusual bets in your sample data according to what you have defined in your question.

> Id: 1, AverageBet: 400, AverageBetTimes10: 4000, Highest bet: 1000
>
> Id: 2, AverageBet: 15, AverageBetTimes10: 150, Highest bet: 20
>
> Id: 3, AverageBet: 110, AverageBetTimes10: 1100, Highest bet: 300
>
> Id: 4, AverageBet: 237.5, AverageBetTimes10: 2375, Highest bet: 300
>
> Id: 5, AverageBet: 73.3333333333333, AverageBetTimes10: 733.333333333333, Highest bet: 100
>
> Id: 6, AverageBet: 162.5, AverageBetTimes10: 1625, Highest bet: 500

Comment: One more question should I use EventID in groupby

Comment: @Santosh - You did not mention anything about EventID in your question so I did not use it. If this is important you need to update your question with what EventID is and how you want to use it to filter your data.

Comment: How to retrieve unusal bets from the above query ?

Comment: @Santosh - the first query produces a list of unusual bets per customer. Good for figuring out if a customer has one or more unusual bets. The second addition / line is a list of all unusual bets.

Comment: @Santosh - by the way I do not see any data that meets that requirement so there are no unusual bets according to your requirements and data.

Comment: I am getting zero record in allUnusualBets

Comment: @Santosh - like I said, you did not provide any data that meets the requirement. In your data there is no customer that has placed a bet higher than 10x their average bet.

Comment: May be this use case help ( All upcoming (i.e. unsettled) bets from customers that win at an unusual rate should be highlighted as risky )

Comment: @Santosh - I feel I have answered your question fairly. If you want to change the requirements or start looking for other anomalies in the data based on additional not listed use cases you should post another question.